# How do I group DATE field by YEAR-MM in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-date-functions

I have a date field in a query and I do want to get GROUP BY report like this:

```
DATE    COUNT
2010-01  10
2010-02  2
...
2010-12  24
2012-13  34
```

What is the proper syntax to obtain this on SQL Server?

Comment: No, that thread was on Mysql syntax, this is SQL Server

Comment: @Mangist: the answer SeanJohnson linked to will work in SQL Server-- and it's much clearer than the answers here

Comment: Wait a minute, what is `2012-13`? Is 13 the week of the year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these conversions to string work, but I find this method more efficient, albeit less readable:

```
SELECT m = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [DATE]), 0), COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.TheTable
  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [DATE]), 0);
```

If you don't want to repeat the expression, then:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT m = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [DATE]), 0)
  FROM dbo.TheTable)
SELECT m, COUNT(*)
  FROM x GROUP BY m;
```

This way the output is still a date/time value and can be used that way for other things. And it doesn't involve any messy string conversions.

Comment: I would think one cast to a string is less work than using  multiple date functions. Is that really more efficient?

Comment: @RedFilter this yields the exact same plan as a single string conversion. The bonus is it stays as a datetime type - so you can format the output if you want, but you can still use it as a datetime type.

Comment: @RedFilter and in fact I can demonstrate exactly why I always use the datetime operations. Under the covers these are really very simple math operations using whole numbers, known to be much more efficient that strings. Exact same query with the conversion/grouping being the only difference is over a second faster using date operations instead of string grouping: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b155e/10

Comment: Thanks for the performance info. I use dates when it makes sense, and strings when specific output is needed (i.e., what I though this question was asking for). I see no need to have a hard and fast rule here.

Comment: @RedFilter If a string is needed in the output, you can always convert on the select list (or in the application, where that presentation formatting belongs anyway) after performing the grouping in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: Number/date math > string manipulation any time. Convert to string at the *last possible moment*. And that's a rule you should follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
select convert(char(7), @myDate, 20)
```

**Example**

```
declare @myDate as DateTime
set @myDate = '2012-06-23'
select convert(char(7), @myDate, 20)
```

**Output**

```
-------
2012-06
```

So the full statement would look like:

```
select convert(char(7), myDate, 20), count(*) as Count
from MyTable
group by convert(char(7), myDate, 20)
```

**Update**

The sample data includes the value `2012-13`. I am going to assume this is a typo and that the number after the dash represents the month.

Comment: Updated to cover the confusing sample data.

Answer (score 2):

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), CreationDate, 120) as Date
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(year, dateCol) as VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(month, dateCol) as VARCHAR) as Date, count(*) As Count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(year, dateCol) as VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(month, dateCol) as VARCHAR)
```

Comment: In fact to get the leading zero on the month you need to use this statement instead SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 120)

Comment: Varchar without length? Nooooooo.... https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand It is documented `varchar` has default length of `30` for purpose of `cast` and `convert`. I use that all the time, while never forgetting to specify a length in any other place.

Comment: @GSerg you may know that, but not all readers do. Please read my blog post - the main point is not that you memorize where it is 30 and where it is 1, but that you code consistently so that you don't have to remember (and that readers don't take the code and use it elsewhere, and then wonder why it breaks).

Comment: Use VARCHAR(4) for the year, and VARCHAR(2) for the month.  In this case it's trivial, so I left it out of the expression.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has `CONCAT` which saves the need to explicitly cast at all.

Comment: This does not return a leading zero on single digit months. It would return '2012-6' rather than '2012-06'. To get a leading zero on the month, you'd need to `RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(month,dateCol) as VARCHAR),2)`. That's a bunch of nested function calls and concatenation to achieve the same result as the simpler `CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),dateCol,20)`